# How can I convert a pathlib.Path object to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I read that `pathlib` is the new Python way to deal with paths.

So I do:

```
with open(pic_name, 'wb') as image:
    image.write(download.content)
    image_path = Path(pic_name).resolve()
    return image_path
```

When I print `image_path` I get the full path to the image, but when I try to pass it to a function that uses ffmpeg to create a video file, I get:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'PosixPath' object to str implicitly

I suspect this is because the object is Posix and the ffmpeg shell command expects a string.

In other cases I also got related error messages like

> TypeError: 'PosixPath' object does not support indexing

or

> TypeError: object of type 'PosixPath' has no len()

So how do you transform a Posix path to a string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python can't do it implicitly, but you can do it explicitly:

```
str(image_path)
```