# Convert WindowsPath to String

Tags: python, filepath, glob, pathlib

```
redpath = os.path.realpath('.')              
thispath = os.path.realpath(redpath)        
fspec = glob.glob(redpath+'/*fits')
thispath = os.path.realpath(thispath+'/../../../..')
p = Path(thispath)
userinput = 'n'
while (userinput == 'n'):
   text_file = next(p.glob('**/*.fits'))
   print("Is this the correct file path?")
   print(text_file)
   userinput = input("y or n")

parent_dir = text_file.parent.resolve()
fspec = glob.glob(parent_dir+'/*fits')
```

I am getting the error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'
```

I think this is because I am trying to glob a Windows File Path when I need to glob a string. Is there a way that I can convert WindowsPath to string so that I can glob all the files into one list?

Comment: Instead of `+` try `os.path.join()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

Comment: Which line of code? You have more info than we do.

Comment: try `type(parent_dir)`, I think it is `WindowsPath` (not str). + operation failing due to different types.

Comment: Two things to consider: pathlib supports glob: [clickme](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) and also relative paths, which can be resolved like `Path(...).resolve()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a pathlib Path object to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641124/how-can-i-convert-a-pathlib-path-object-to-a-string)

Answer (score 48):

As most other Python classes do, the `WindowsPath` class, from `pathlib`, implements a non-defaulted "*dunder string*" method (`__str__`). It turns out that the string representation returned by that method for that class is exactly the string representing the filesystem path you are looking for. Here an example:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('E:\\x\\y\\z')
>>> WindowsPath('E:/x/y/z')

p.__str__()
>>> 'E:\\x\\y\\z'

str(p)
>>> 'E:\\x\\y\\z'
```

The `str` builtin function actually calls the "*dunder string*" method under the hood, so the results are exaclty the same. By the way, as you can easily guess calling directly the "*dunder string*" method avoids a level of indirection by resulting in faster execution time.

Here the results of the tests I've done on my laptop:

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit(lambda:str(p),number=10000000)
>>> 2.3293891000000713

timeit(lambda:p.__str__(),number=10000000)
>>> 1.3876856000000544
```

Even if calling the `__str__` method may appear a bit uglier in the source code, as you saw above, it leads to faster runtimes.

Comment: The str(variable) solved a similar problem for me whilst piping from pathLib.Path(variable) with a string variable Frankensteinian stitching operating.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that you shouldn't call [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) directly. You should always use str() / len() / ... because they check the return type (in this case it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 4):

You are right, you need a string when you call `glob.glob`. In the last line of your code, `parent_dir` is a `pathlib.Path` object, which you cannot concatenate with the string `'/*fits'`. You need to explicitly convert `parent_dir` to a string by passing it to the built-in `str` function.

The last line of your code should thus read:

```
fspec = glob.glob(str(parent_dir)+'/*fits')
```

To illustrate further, consider this example:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path('C:\\')
>>> path
WindowsPath('C:/')
>>> str(path)
'C:\\'
>>>
```

Comment: Pathlib supports glob: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob